# Mongo Atlas Search: Find Exact Document Matches

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Trying to use Mongo Atlas Search aggregation to find documents that precisely match my query which contains a list of 100 - 200 words.

Start of my aggregation query

```
{
  '$search': {
     'index': 'default',
     'text': {
       'query': 'yellow pizza blue ',
       'path': 'word'
      }
   }
}, {...
```

My collection

```
{
  "word": "yellow card"
},
{
  "word": "pizza"
},
{
  "word": "blue"
}
```

I need  it to return “**pizza, blue**", instead it returns “**yellow card, pizza, blue**”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need a simple substring search using `$indexOfCP`

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $ne: [
      -1,
      {
        $indexOfCP: [
          "yellow pizza blue ",
          "$word"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mCwWMULqpnk)

---

If your search list is a space-separated list, you can consider `$split` the `words` field and your search list into arrays and perform `$setIsSubset` to find the matches.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "searchList": "yellow pizza blue investment "
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "searchList": {
        "$split": [
          "$searchList",
          " "
        ]
      },
      tokens: {
        "$split": [
          "$word",
          " "
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$setIsSubset": [
          "$tokens",
          "$searchList"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "tokens",
      "searchList"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nT2OWlXPBAr)

Comment: thanks, I had never heard of $indexOfCP until now.  I tried out it, problem is if my collection has both "invest" and "investment", and I search on "investment" it returns both.

Comment: and the other thing is that my query can contain between 100 - 200 words, I will update the original post, I failed to mention that.

Comment: @user2574678 based on an assumption that your search list is a space-separated list, updated the answer to provide another alternative

Comment: Thanks Ray, that worked, thank you for sharing, I have much to learn here.